# CSS width значение в пикселях с плавающей точкой можно?

Tags: css3, css

```
width: 15.555px;
```

так можно?

Вот так точно можно

```
width: 15.555%;
```

Answer (score 4):

[Проведём эксперимент](http://jsfiddle.net/ZtXLz/):

```js
alert($(wrapper).width());
```

```css
.fwidth {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40.25px;
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="fwidth">1</div>
  <div class="fwidth">2</div>
  <div class="fwidth">3</div>
  <div class="fwidth">4</div>
</div>
```

Подробно об этом написано [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length) или [здесь](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#lengths), и ещё про [number](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#number).

Резюмируя - по стандарту, css свойство

- width имеет значение типа length либо , [percentage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/percentage)
- length в свою очередь определено как number за которым следует обозначение единицы (px,pt, in, etc),
- number определен как целое число (или ноль) десятичных цифр за которыми следует точка, за которой следуют десятичные цифры. ( например .1 0.1 12.123 )

Нигде не сказано о частном случае px (что он должен быть целым например),  таким образом ответ - да можно.

Answer (score 0):

Да, можно, но работает сомнительно (по крайней мере, в хроме):

```css
div {
  width: 1.555px;
  height: 1.455px;
  background: red;
}

div + div {
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  background: silver;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  transform: scale(100);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
```